# Recuperar el valor de una caja de texto ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Tengo una `textbox` con el id `TextBox` y

Tengo una función JavaScript

```
function prueba() {
  var hotel = document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML;
  $('#MainContent_TextBox1').val(hotel);
}
```

Ahora en el `codebehind` quiero que el valor que asigné al `Textbox`, recuperar lo

```
 public void printDivs()
 {
   eWidget hotel = new eWidget();
   hotel.titulo = TextBox1.Text;
 }
```

Pero cuando `debugeo`, me dice que no tiene nada ese `textbox`, aunque visualmente si tiene

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza:

```
$('#MainContent_TextBox1').val(hotel);
```

Por:

```
$('#<%= NombreDeTuTextBox.ClientID %>').val(hotel);
```

Explicación:

La definición de los IDs a nivel de cliente en ASP.net Webforms depende de la forma en que utilizas el Site.Master, los placeholders de contenido, para asegurarte que estás seleccionando el ID (cliente) que esperas es necesario especificarlo mediante `.ClientID`

Comment: Ok, me pareece bien, gracias

Comment: de esta forma ya podre obtener su valor en el codebehind?

Comment: de nada bro, en el codeBehind lo llamas así: NombreDeTuTextBox.Text :D